# how to check what post data is passed by curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to debug a curl request and check what **post arguments** were passed in the request.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, MERCHANT_CONFIG_PATH.'/cacert.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    var_export(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

but I only see this

```
[request_header] => POST /nvp HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 728
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Does this mean the post data wasn't included in the request?

Comment: please can you post full code? how you init curl and what's inside $data

Comment: @Oleksandr Khavdiy You could upvote my answer as well if it solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That doesn't mean your POST data wasn't included into request. CURL doesn't always output content of sent data, it depends on your server settings. However you don't need to see that content because CURL send POST data exactly as it given in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option. The only exception is when you set this option to an array. But even in this case you can forecast exact content of sent data by reproducing manipulations CURL perform with given array (`http_build_data` and `urlencode`) and comparing length of the result with value of `Content-Length` request header.